# How to Remove Dynamically Added Controls in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am not able to delete dynamically added controls in button click event. Let me know how to do this.

```
public void populateform(ArrayList list)
{
  int i = 1;
  int count = 0;

  foreach (string cartitems in list)
  {
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Name = "myLabel"+i;

    lbl.Content = cartitems.ToString();
    mystackpanel.Children.Add(lbl);
    i++;
    ++count;
    if (count % 3 == 0)
    {
      Button btndelete = new Button();
      btndelete.Content = "Delete";

      btndelete.Width = 120;
      btndelete.Height = 35;
      btndelete.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btndelete_Click);

      mystackpanel.Children.Add(btndelete);                    
    }
  }
}

private void btndelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Label lbl2 = (Label)this.mystackpanel.FindName("myLabel2");
  this.mystackpanel.Children.Remove(lbl2);               
}
```

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI Elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Post a screenshot of what you need so we can tell you the right way to do it in WPF.

Comment: And why in the world are you using an untyped `ArrayList`? this is not java for God's sake. Use a proper generic `List<T>` or something

Comment: @HighCore That's not true. Creating elements is perfectly acceptable, but I would definitely agree that a bound list is a far better way of doing it.

Comment: @alski "perfectly acceptable"? Under what circumstances? why would you choose a crappy procedural approach over the correct one? please dude.

Comment: @user2613455 What are you trying to do here? Add three labels then add a delete button?

Comment: @Highcore "perfectly acceptable" in that it compiles and runs, and that its also in the MSDN documentation as how it *can* be done. I would suggest from the rest of the code snippet above that it will probably fit with user2613455's knowledge, so that we wouldn't be drowning them in too much knowledge at once.

Comment: @Alski I disagree. teaching crappy practices (which btw require a lot more code) than the correct approach is not necessary under any circumnstances, regardless of the level of knowledge of the individual. an `ItemsControl` approach is much cleaner and teaches the WPF mentality up front.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Remarks section in [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx):

> FindName operates within the current element's namescope. For details, see [WPF XAML Namescopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx).

In short, you have to call `RegisterName` in order to make `FindName` work for dynamically created elements.

```
lbl.Name = "myLabel" + i;
lbl.Content = cartitems;
mystackpanel.Children.Add(lbl);
mystackpanel.RegisterName(lbl.Name, lbl); // here
```

---

It might however be easier to find an element by name like shown below, without using `FindName`.

```
var element = mystackpanel.Children
    .OfType<FrameworkElement>()
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "myLabel2")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Label lbl = (Label)LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(mystackpanel, "myLabelx");
mystackpanel.Children.Remove(lbl);
```

Comment: Worked well on my canvas element. +1